# Bulma: how to nicely mark in navbar the current tab of website I'm in?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'd like to nicely mark in navbar the current tab I'm in on my website using Bulma.

[image]

I've tried is-tab, `is-active` and `aria-current="page"` but it did not work. It presents like this and the current tab **"About me"** is not marked in any way.

Let's say the code snippet looks like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-color is-fixed-top" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item">
            <img src="static/Gimilov.png" width="130" height="50" />
        </a>

        <a class="navbar-burger" id="burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample" role="button">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-menu" id="nav-links" id="navbarBasicExample">
        <div class="navbar-start">
            <a class="navbar-item has-text-white" href="/">
                About me
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-item has-text-white" href="/projects">
                Projects
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-item has-text-white" href="/resume">
                Resume and certifications
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-item has-text-white" href="/recommendations">
                Recommendations
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                <a class="navbar-link has-text-white">
                    More
                </a>

                <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                    <a class="navbar-item" href="/experience">
                        Experience
                    </a>
                    <hr class="navbar-divider" />
                    <a class="navbar-item" href="/whygimilov">
                        Why Gimilov?
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In fact, the `is-active` class works fine in your code, but you don't notice it visually, because the color of this class is `#0a0a0a`. Here is a screen - https://i.ibb.co/hVQ4wjG/image.png. Look closely and you will see a difference in color.

Comment: Okay, I tried to dig a little into styles.css and it appears that I had messed a little with that eventually. I redesigned the code a little (and everything seems to work right now).

I added is-tab and is-active to each and now the current tab is distinguishable well. Used some jinja2 syntax to indicate which page I'm in right now. 

Thanks!

Comment: @s.kuznetsov: you gave a very good answer and it works. Please, don't hide it in a comment! The other answer is terrible!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

If you check the code of https://bulma.io/videos/ , you can see that the menu button looks like this:

```
<a class="navbar-item bd-navbar-item bd-navbar-item-videos bd-navbar-item-base is-active" href="https://bulma.io/videos/">
    <span class="icon has-text-success">
        <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
    </span>
    <span>Videos</span>
</a>
```

It's the `.bd-navbar-item.is-active` CSS that adds the border. Adding `is-active` to the anchor class might be enough for your page to work.

Comment: Well, I do not really understand what I should do. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have no idea how you have created that site or how Bulma works. If you can change your About me anchor to `<a class="navbar-item has-text-white is-active" href="/">About me</a>`, perhaps that would work.

Comment: Well, I did that already and nothing changed :/

Comment: According to their 239 kB file, `a.navbar-item.is-active` should have a bright gray background with blue text color. Are you sure that you are not overriding that somehow?

Comment: I've checked my styles.css and I did not mess with that.

However, if it matters, I was of course modifying the navbar by changing its colors etc. Still, I do not remember messing with that attribute.

Comment: Right-click the anchor, inspect element and check its CSS properties and what sets them. I have to sleep now. :)